# How I can upload an image to a remote Mongo fs.grid?

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I am trying to upload a remote image to Mongo fs.grid. I want to do that without a view, just with a model.

I have an "example" here: https://gist.github.com/matysanchez/8607114

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/nateabele/photoblog - I'm pretty sure it has code to do this.

Comment: @rmarscher thank for you comment. I have seen that code. The code use fs.grid and actually upload the image, but.. from a form with a local image, not with a external.

Comment: Ok, I'll fork your gist and see if I can get it working.

Comment: @rmarscher I could do it, please check it out: https://gist.github.com/matysanchez/8607114

Answer (score 0):

After try and search a lot. I could do it.

Here you have: https://gist.github.com/matysanchez/8607114